# Как избавиться от исключения "вызов функции PInvoke разбалансировал стек"

Tags: c#, pinvoke

Пытаюсь написать код для управления машинкой Formula Allcode. Управление осуществляется путем вызова  функций из dll файла. Функции объявлены  в отдельном классе FA_DLL. Функций очень много,поэтому как пример приведу только 3 (для открытия, закрытия порта и поворот вправо).

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
namespace WindowsFormsApp6
{
    class FA_DLL
    {
        [DllImport("FASlave.dll")]
        public static extern char FA_ComOpen(char Port);
        [DllImport("FASlave.dll")]
        public static extern char FA_ComClose(char Port);
        [DllImport("FASlave.dll")]
        public static extern void FA_Right(char Port, uint angle);
    }
}
```

Проблема в том,что при попытке открыть порт или передать какую либо команду я получаю исключение

**Помощник по отладке управляемого кода "PInvokeStackImbalance" : "Вызов функции PInvoke "WindowsFormsApp6!WindowsFormsApp6.FA_DLL::FA_Right" разбалансировал стек. Вероятно, это вызвано тем, что управляемая сигнатура PInvoke не совпадает с неуправляемой целевой сигнатурой. Убедитесь, что соглашение о вызовах и параметры сигнатуры PInvoke совпадают с неуправляемой целевой сигнатурой**

Причем исключение появляется случайно - то, при открытии порта,то при передаче любой другой команды (почти всегда при вызове команды "повернуть вправо",а иногда все прекрасно работает (очень редко) причем в коде ничего не меняется. В чем может быть ошибка? 
Функции вызываю вот так

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Port = (char)3;
    FA_DLL.FA_ComOpen(Port);
}
```

Или

```
FA_DLL.FA_Right(Port, (uint)angle);
```

Comment: Как эти функции определены в C++?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Я не знаю,так как они определены в dll файле(скорее всего),а как его открыть я не представляю.

Comment: Откуда вы взяли сигнатуры функций? Их названия и параметры: char, uint?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov В папке с мануалом по использованию машинки был сам dll файл и cs файл в котором были обьявлены все функции. В этом же мануале было написано подключить к проекту файл с обьявлениями и закинуть dll. После этого можно вызывать функции

Comment: @Fate в таком случае, обращайтесь к автору мануала

Comment: @PavelMayorov В этом-то и проблема, мануал составлен самим производителем машинки и 100% рабочий,так как у других эти функции работают более чем хорошо. Я просто не совсем понимаю чем вообще это исключение вызывается,а следовательно не понимаю как его исправить.В функцию передаются не те аргументы? Или проблема может быть в неправильном подключении dll? Или что-то другое?

Comment: @Fate исключение означает, что у вызванной функции неправильная сигнатура. А знает правильную, с ваших слов, только автор мануала.

Comment: @Fate А "мануал составлен самим производителем машинки"* - это вовсе не гарантия того, что он 100% рабочий.

Comment: @PavelMayorov Но,как я уже говорил,у других эти функции работают, значит ошибка где-то на моей стороне.

Comment: На вашей стороне, действительно, есть ошибки: функции Open и Close возвращают значение. Вы его не проверяете. Возможно, порт не открылся, а вы начинаете с ним работать. Но это так, примечание.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov ,но таких,которые могли бы вызвать это исключение нет?

Comment: Пару минут погуглил. Похоже, в оригинале именно `char` - однобайтовый символ. Между тем в дотнете чар двухбайтовый. Попробуйте в сигнатурах всех функций заменить `char` на `byte`.

Comment: @Fate Ну как же они работают-то, когда они исключение кидают?!

Answer (score 5):

Начать с того, что это не исключение, а диагностическое сообщение CLR (которое автоматически включено при запуске под отладчиком). Оно действительно может выводиться через раз, так как невозможно автоматически определить каждый выстрел в ногу с некорректным использованием P/Invoke, но ложной тревогой оно является редко.

Как исправить? Сделать то, что написано - привести объявление P/Invoke в соответствие с реальным прототипом функции. Если загрузить с сайта [AllCode](https://www.matrixtsl.com/allcode/resources/) пример для С++, в заголовочном файле можно найти такое объявление:

```
__declspec(dllimport) unsigned char FA_ComOpen( unsigned char Port );
```

Оно уже не соответствует вашему. Во-первых, не указанное соглашение о вызове - это cdecl, а в P/Invoke по умолчанию - stdcall. Во-вторых, Типу unsigned char в C# соответствует byte, а не char. Если предположить, что объявление для С++ правильное, объявление для C# должно выглядеть так:

```
[DllImport("FASlave.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
static extern byte FA_ComOpen(byte Port);
```

Comment: @Fate - проблема решена?